# how to loop inside ajax from input field value?

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to loop inside ajax from input field values in the php as control? i want to display the word 'copy' based on the desired number of test case.  See below:

**php:**

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" id="problem_form">                            <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label"> Number of Test Case/s </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="test_case" id="test_case" />
                                <input type="submit" onclick="Cchecker.validate_problem_post(this)" name="test_case_btn" id="test_case_btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Go" />
                            </div>
                        </div><hr/>
                        <div id="test_case_container"></div>
                </form>
```

As you can see, I have an onclick event in Go button.  it calls the ajax function which is found below.

**ajax:**

```
validate_problem_post: function(){
                        submitHandler: function (form) {
                for(var i = 0; i < $('#test_case'); i++){
                    $('#test_case_container').html('copy');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Everytime I execute it, the program only prints the word 'copy' one time instead of following $('#test_case')'s content.

Comment: it could help to make the question more specific

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in the loop's condition. You have to fix it:

```
for(var n = $('#test_case').val(), i = 0; i < n; i++) {...}
```

Comment: I did it this way but still it doesn't work.

submitHandler: function (form) {
          var n = $('#test_case').val();

          for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           $('#test_case_container').html('copy');
          }
         }